# Installing multiple RSA SSL certificates with Apache for one website

Tags: apache, ssl, sha1

Is it possible to install multiple RSA certificates for one website with Apache (same domains)? My predicament is this:

We have an old client that communicates with our webserver through a custom C++ application (not a web browser), and it is absolutely impossible for us to update it to use a modern cipher for modern SSL certificates. It is hardcoded to use SHA1 and like I said, it can not be updated.

On the same server that this client device communicates with also lives a website. We need to update things so that when people use a web browser and navigate to our site, we are issuing a modern SSL cert. But, when the old client device is communicating with this server's api over https, we want to secure it using our old sha1 certificate. (Yes, yes, I know...)

I was led to believe that with Apache, you could simply add additional SSLCertificateFile & SSLCertifcateKeyFile entries for each certificate, and then the underlying TSL implementation on clients would handle negotiating which certificate it gets. But upon further testing and reading the last sentence on the documentation for these, I'm not so sure. It says:

> This directive can be used up to three times (referencing different filenames) when both a RSA, a DSA, and an ECC based server certificate is used in parallel.

[Source](http://ssh.dukejournals.org/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSLCertificateFile)

I'm supposing my question is answered right there, but since it does not explicitly state you can't use two RSA certificates for the purpose I'm seeking and that we can't be the only ones to have this problem (unable to update legacy client), I have to ask.

Thank you : )

Comment: "Is it possible to install multiple certificates" Of course yes. The quote you have is if you want to include multiple certificates for the same website (same hostname) then it is up to 3 only, an RSA version, a DSA one, and an ECC one. But thanks to SNI you can have multiple hostnames, so separate your application from your website and apply different cryptographic configuration. Besides that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying I can only use a single RSA cert for www.mysite.com (a single hostname). And when you say divide, I'll need to create a new host either through some subdomain or what have you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Server Name Identification (SNI) is an extension of the SSL/TLS protocol that makes possible for Apache to use trusted certificates for a single site.

SNI permits a server to use different SSL certificates over the same IP address.

To use multiple SSL Certificates on your server you need to create new Virtual Host.

Source -

https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm
https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/server-name-indication-sni-use-multiple-ssl-on-a-single-ip